# Select a node from a JSON file that matches a property value

Tags: json, powershell

I am having a json object stored in a variable. From the json object, I want to fetch the node which matches a value. For example - an item having machineId 12.

My json looks like

```
{
    "items":  [
              {
                  "id":  "asdasd",
                  "machineId":  "12",
                  "placementGroup":  "",
                  "region":  "158",
                  "staticIp":  "",
                  "staticIpAction":  "",
                  "subnetIDs":  [

                                ]

              },
              {
                  "id":  "asdasd",
                  "machineId":  "43",
                  "placementGroup":  "",
                  "region":  "158",
                  "staticIp":  "",
                  "staticIpAction":  "",
                  "subnetIDs":  [

                                ]
              }
          ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the json using the `Get-Content` cmdlet and convert it to json using the `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet. Select the *items*  node and filter it by the desired *machineId*  using the `Where-Object` cmdlet:

```
Get-Content 'yourPathToYour.json' | 
    ConvertFrom-Json |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty items |
    Where-Object machineId -eq 12
```

---

**Output:**

```
id             : asdasd
machineId      : 12
placementGroup : 
region         : 158
staticIp       : 
staticIpAction : 
subnetIDs      : {}
```

Comment: Beware that `ConvertFrom-Json` requires PowerShell 3+.